# それぞれ and ずつ use and differences

Tags: words

I'm a bit confused by それぞれ and ずつ.

What would the difference be between these three sentences:

> それぞれの生徒にオレンジを二個ずつあげた
>
> 生徒にオレンジを二個ずつあげた
>
> それぞれの生徒にオレンジを二個あげた

Comment: Related? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42891/9831

Comment: I see sometimes それぞれ used with ずつ and sometimes without it because それぞれ is enough.  And in the third sentence それぞれ is used both.  So... what's the difference?